# How to obtain the referenced Bundle of a bundle-entry URL?

Tags: url, osgi, osgi-bundle

In an OSGi environment `ClassLoader.getResource()` typically returns a bundle-entry/bundle-resource URL (using a corresponding protocol).
The [OSGi specification chapter 3.9.6 - "Resource Loading"](https://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.core/8.0.0/framework.module.html#i3178562) specifies only a few aspects how those URLs have to be constructed (for example the path) and leafs everything else to the implementation.

Is it possible, and if yes how, to obtain the Bundle to which a bundle-entry URL is pointing, using only implementation-independent OSGi API?

For example for a jar-URL one can open a connection, cast it to `JarURLConnection` and use `JarURLConnection.getJarFile()` to obtain the JarFile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible, and if yes how, to obtain the Bundle to which a bundle-entry URL is pointing, using only implementation-independent OSGi API?

Not in a specified way. The OSGi specification deliberately leaves URL details opaque to allow implementation freedom to the framework.

For specific framework implementations, you may be able to discern the bundle id in the URL. But this is subject to change at the desires of the framework implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
At the moment my work-around approach is to compute the URL-host of a resource from each bundle, which is stored in a map that associates the host to the bundle-ID and to track all bundles and hopefully get notified once the wiring changes (and with that maybe the host), which is cumbersome and maybe not reliable.

Do you think there is a chance that OSGi will provide means to get the target bundle of a bundle-entry URL? If so I can create an issue on the OSGi github page.